# Can't load the URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the apps domains - add all subdomains and domains

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get a Facebook app to work, and I am including my domains and my subdomains in my app domains.

I have:

```
v2.name.com

id.v2.name.com

name.com
```

the call is going to id.v2.name.com, but for some reason it just isn't working.

What setting do I need to put for the Facebook app to make this work?

Comment: What call? Be specific about when exactly in the process you are getting this error.

Comment: This is when trying to login via identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

This was related to not having a valid redirect URI for my application.

Personally I feel the error message should be clearer for this problem, as it indicates the problem is with the App Domains, when it is not